# MySQL- Fetching multiple records from same table

Tags: mysql

First of all, sorry for the bad title. I am in little hurry and couldn't think of a better one.

Now I have a table like this -

```
category_id    name        parent_category_id
______________________________________
1              country     0
2              state       1
3              city        2
4              block       3
```

And I want results as -

```
Name        ParentCategory
___________________________
country     NULL
state       country
city        state
block       city
```

Now the logic is ParentCategory is category name whose category_id is equal to parent_category_id. (Not sure if I explained it properly) I tried a lot writing a query for this, but don't know how can I do it.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a JOIN of the table with itself:

```
SELECT child.name, parent.name FROM tbl AS child
    LEFT JOIN tbl AS parent
    ON (child.parent_category__id = parent.category_id);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
  child.name AS Name,
  parent.name AS ParentCategory
FROM
  yourTableName AS child
  LEFT JOIN yourTableName AS parent ON parent.category_id=child.parent_category_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   c.name  Name,
         p.name  ParentCategory
FROM  t  c
LEFT JOIN t  p 
ON p.category_id=c.parent_category_id;
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2983/8)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name FROM table as t1 LEFT JOIN table as t2 ON t1.parent_category_id=t2.category_id
```

Comment: and this one (left join instead inner)?